# multiplying a column vector by a transition matrix P (of a Markov Chain) on the left

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I want to know what information can we infer from multiplying a column vector $f$ by a transition matrix $P$ (of a Markov Chain) on the left.

I was reading a book and they said that:

We might think of $f$ as function on the state space $\chi$.

The $x^{th}$ entry of $Pf$ tells us the expected value of the function $f$ at the next state given that we are at the state $x$.

I didn't understand it quite well.

Comment: Does it help if you translate this interpretation into the more formal statement $Pf(x)=E(f(X_1)|X_0=x)$?

Comment: thank you @Mars it's clear !

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Markov chain with transitions given by $P$, with $P_{i,j}=\Pr(X_{t+1}=j\,\vert\, X_t=i)$. Thinking of $f$ as both a function and a vector with $f(j)=f_j$, we have
$$
(Pf)_i=\sum_{j=1}^n P_{i,j}f_j=\sum_{j=1}^n \Pr(X_{t+1}=j\,\vert\, X_t=i)f(j)=\mathbb{E}[f(X_{t+1})\vert X_t=i],
$$
just using the definition of expectation. This is exactly what you wrote in words.

Comment: Thanks ! I threw all the probability definitions behind while studying stochastic processes ...